# Connected iPhone no longer showing in Mac Photos app

Tags: iphone, photos.app, import

When I connect my iPhone to a MacBook Pro it does no longer show up in the sidebar of the Mac Photos app. This e.g. prevents me from importing photos from the iPhone.

Can this be due to some changed configuration setting in the iPhone's iOS (9.1) or the MacBook Pro's OS X (10.1.1 with Photos 1.2)? I want to be sure I have this base covered before bringing the iPhone to a store for a hardware check.

Comment: Can Image Capture or iTunes see it?

Comment: @Tetsujin Good point: iTunes sees the iPhone. Image Capture apparently not ("Devices: 0", "No camera or scanner connected"), but I not well familiar with this Mac app.

Comment: I'd be inclined to test whether it will sync/backup to iTunes; then restore if necessary

Comment: @Tetsujin syncing in iTunes works fine (i.e. Mac copies e.g. podcasts to, receives backup from iPhone). The issue really seems to be confined to visibility (or connectivity) of the iPhone in the Mac Photos app.

Comment: All I can think to do is power cycle/restore. It's not as if there's any on/off switch I'm aware of that could have been toggled

Comment: @Tetsujin Just to make sure I understand correctly: you suggestion is for turning the iPhone on/off and then restoring it from the most recent backup? (I am willing to try that, if applicable.)

Comment: It's the best I can think of - run a new backup first, of course, if there are significant changes since your last one, & use Encrypted backup, to save passwords etc