# Photos app no longer sees my phone

Tags: macos, photos, android

I have an android phone connected using PTP over USB. (A Fairphone FP1)

OSX used to launch Photo's every single time I plugged in the phone to charge, which was very annoying, so I unticked the box that said "Open Photos for this device"

Now Photo's cannot see the device. Not at all. Not ever.

If I open Photo's manually, the device is not shown at all in the sidebar or anywhere else.

I also checked [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/214487/connected-iphone-no-longer-showing-in-mac-photos-app) and the phone doesn't appear in the devices on Image Capture either.

Any suggestions how I can get photos of this device again?

Comment: I'm experiencing exactly the same issue with an HTC First.  Any luck with a resolution?  Have you tried a different USB cable?

Comment: Its not a connectivity issue, I can still use other apps to access it. No resolution found :-(